# How to write "#!/bin/sh" to script.sh through bash?

Tags: bash

I need a bash string, which writes to my.sh this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
uci -q batch <<-EOF > /dev/null
    set wireless.@wifi-iface[0].ssid='WVADSUP'
    set wireless.@wifi-device[0].disabled=0
    commit wireless
EOF
exit 0
```

I try echo "#!/bin/sh" >> wifi_on , but it doesn`t work.

Comment: `but it doesn't work` - what does it mean? How does it "not work"? How do you detect "not working"? Are you interested in how to write `#!/bin/sh` into a file named `wifi_on`, or do you want to write it all? Because you can for example `cat >wifi_on <<'EOF2'` + copy the whole script + type `EOF2`.

Comment: @tevemadar YES! thats it!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' >> wifi_on
```

That`s it

Answer (score 0):

You can't (easily) prepend to a file, but you can *edit* the file.

```
ed wifi_on <<'SCRIPT'
1i
#!/bin/sh
uci -q batch <<-EOF > /dev/null
    set wireless.@wifi-iface[0].ssid='WVADSUP'
    set wireless.@wifi-device[0].disabled=0
    commit wireless
EOF
exit 0
.
wq
SCRIPT
```